# How to resize split screen size in byobu

Tags: byobu

Currently, my byobu split screens look like this (i.e. they are of unequal size -- the rightmost split size is much smaller than the leftmost split size, for example):

[image]

Is there a way to resize those splits? I want to make the rightmost split wider and the leftmost split narrower.

Comment: It looks like `Ctrl-a Ctrl-Arrows`.

Comment: Note: for ctx's solution to work Ctrl-a needs to be byobu's escape sequence. This can be set by running byobu-ctrl-a

Comment: @ctx: Thanks, you saved my day. With MobaXTerm, Shift-Alt-Fn Key didn't work

Answer (score 24):

From the byobu help menu <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>:

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+[←↑→↓].

Comment: The `Shift+Alt+(direction)` worked like a charm even using a BitVise SSH Client