# How to equalize byobu vertical split screen size

Tags: administration, byobu, terminal-multiplexer

Note: I may be leaning on an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); feel free to steer me to a more ideal approach.

> I want to keep an eye on multiple remote log files in a small-yet-legible font,
>   
>   **not so much analyzing content as peripherally noticing sudden bursts in activity**.

I'm trying to create a Byobu script to tail log files on six remote servers.

I'm used to Vim, but Byobu calls it a vertical split:

[image]

Scripted splits chop existing terminals in half, rendering each split smaller, leading to `create pane failed: pane too small` and a window with vanishing perspective:

[image: Terminal panes uneven splits]

I'm new to Byobu.  There's surely a way to select a different pane, execute a command, then split, but I can't seem to get the syntax (order?) right.

I expect there's also a command to just "equalize" all panes at once.  That would be even more handy.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391814/how-to-resize-split-screen-size-in-byobu) has the manual, unscripted version of what I need.

Years ago I used GNU screen similarly, and it worked great--except using a GUI all day conditions me to use the mouse, so switching between terminals feels clunky.  Maybe screen is still the smartest solution.  Or tmux?  I'm not married to Byobu's chyron readout.

As windows split they divide by 50%, so I'm willing to accept eight terminals if the even halving leads to a smoother execution.

Thanks in advance--any thoughts?

Comment: Byobu actually used to be based on GNU Screen.

Comment: I thought it was based on t-mux.  Interesting--thanks.

Comment: Or rather a frontend script for t-mux.

Comment: Well now it is, but originally it wasn't.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> hot key to rearrange the splits.  You can press it multiple times to cycle through a couple of arrangements that equalizes the spacing of the splits there.

```
    Shift-F8                     Toggle through split arrangements
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.org)*

Comment: I need something automated that can be put into a script.  Basically (screen one: ssh server1; split; select screen two: ssh server2; split) et cetera.  All attempts so far have reduced the vertical headroom to the point of failure.  Thanks for replying--the UI is really nice!  I think my use here is underkill for Byobu.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years late but in case others come across this question, there is a layout called `even-vertical` and you can select this layout at the commandline with:

```
byobu select-layout even-vertical
```

I'm surprised Dustin didn't offer this as an alternative. :)